# ASP ImageButton vs Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspbutton

I am new to asp.net stuff and I am pretty confused on how to fix this problem. I have the back code written for everything and right now I am just making everything "look pretty". Originally I had an ASP button to submit a form for something. Now I want the button to be an ASP ImageButton. However now my method is returning an error due to this change. This is what it looks like:

```
 //.ascx file
 <div id="eSubmit">
    <asp:ImageButton id="btnSubmit1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Style/Images/addButtonE.png" />
</div>


 //method behind
 void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsValid) { return; }

        try
        {
            //do some data checking
            //bind entries
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ax)
        {
            ;
        }
    }
```

The error that is generated after changing the button to imagebutton is:

> Cannot convert 'System.EventHandler' to
>   'System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventHandler'

So my main question is: How do I fix this error? And will this effect the data I am sending to the server in anyway (will this cause different behavior then when it was just a button)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following line

`protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)`

instead of

`void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Because Image button has different event handler ..
Thanks 
Gourav

Comment: This was it. Thank you loads. The others got me to fix some other things but this got the last error go to away.

Answer (score 3):

[`ImageButton.OnClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.onclick.aspx) has a different event signature than [`Button.OnClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx):

```
//imagebutton
void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    //.......
}

//button
void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //.......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...
copy previous method code (in btnSubmit_Click), then delete whole method, go to UI (in design mode) double click the image button & paste the copied code & run